# Barcode Font inside HTML Table tag not render correctly. But outside work perfectly

Tags: css, html

Barcode in ***table thead*** tag render not correctly as code and image show below

```
<table id="BranchReturnReportDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="6" id="docBarcode" style="text-align:center" class="barcode">*8851234567890*</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Column A</th>
            <th>Column B</th>
            <th>Column C</th>
            <th>Column D</th>
            <th>Column E</th>
            <th>Column F</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="BranchReturnReportDataTableBody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Barcode render show like this

[image]

But when I use it outside table it work like a charm.

```
<p id="docBarcode" class="box-title barcode" style="text-align:center">*8851234567890*</p>
```

[image]

Both code use this same **css** code

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'C39HrP72DlTt';
  src: url('V100018.TTF');
}

.barcode {
    font-family: 'C39HrP72DlTt';
    font-size: 6em;
    /*padding: 10px;*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default browser style for the table header seems to set the `font-weight` to `bold`, causing it not to appear correctly. To fix this, change your CSS to

```
.barcode {
  font-family:'C39HrP72DlTt';
  font-size: 6em;
  font-weight: normal;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
}
```